# Update a timestamp in a database and add +1 to a value at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sql-update

I have a table called ratings and I want to run a statement to update the table setting the column rate1 to + 1 of the value currently in the column and I want to update the column 'lastSubDate' to the current timestamp. I figured the SQL would look something like this although this doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `ratings` 
SET (`rate1`, `lastSubDate`)
VALUES (+1, NOW())  
WHERE `ProductId` = 9996637
```

I would appreciate any help if you could let me know where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
UPDATE
  `ratings` 
SET
  `rate1`=`rate1`+1,
  `lastSubDate`=NOW()
WHERE
  `ProductId` = 9996637
```